# How to send mail using Java in a Linux environment?

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I have successfully sent mail using Java using apache james server in Windows. I have been trying to do the same in Linux, but couldn't start the james server. I am a novice in Linux.

Is james server really necessary for sending mails? If so how to start james server in Linux?

Comment: What's the problem or error you're getting?

Comment: Special privileges are needed to use port 25 under Unix systems.

Comment: "Is james server really necessary for sending mails." no. At least for the way you worded the question, the answer is no.

Comment: You don't need a complete mail server for sending mail. A simple SMTP client is enough if you already have a remote SMTP server.

Comment: It is not necessary. What's the error with James?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending emails in java you can use the java mail api: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html 
See this tutorial for infos about using it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

They are using a mail server on localhost, but i wouldn't recommend that. It is perfectly alright for testing or if your localhost is a server with proper DNS records. If you send emails from a IP where DNS reverse lookup does not work, chances are that your mail will be stopped by a spam filter.

If you want a mailserver on localhost you could install exim, postfix, ssmtp or any other MTA from your linux distribution. It's possible that one of them is already installed and running.

I would use some other mail server for example the one you are using to send emails. This line of code from the tutorial configures the host:

```
  // Setup mail server
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
```